# Trying to perform subspace iteration by applying a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^3$ repeately to a matrix $S$, but its not working?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fixed-point-iteration

I am trying to perform subspace iteration in MatLab but I am not getting the results I expected. 
Let the matrices $A$ and $S$ be given by
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
S =
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 & 6 \\
9 & 5 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

$A$ clearly has the eigenvalues $5, 3$, and $2$, and $S$ defines a subspace of dimension $k = 2$. I then assumed that repeated application of $A$ to $S$, followed by normalization, should 'push' the subspace represented by $S$ to the subspace given by the 2 dominant eigenvectors (the ones associated with eigenvalues $5$ and $3$) of $A$. I would have expected to end up with a matrix very close to the following matrix $M$, after performing many iterations:
$$
M = A^k S =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.6 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
as $k$ becomes large.

However, when I perform this iterative process in MatLab I end up with a one-dimensional matrix
$$
\hat{M} \approx
\begin{pmatrix}
0.38 & 0.51 & 0.76 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I thought iteration with the matrix $A$ should take matrix $S$ to the $2$ dominant eigenvectors of $A$. So why hasn't it?

**Edit**

Here is my code:

```
A = [ 5, 0, 0 ; 0, 3, 0; 0, 0, 2 ];
S = [ 3, 4, 6; 9, 5, 2;, 0, 0, 0];

jMax = 20;
for j=1:jMax
    S = A*S/norm(A*S);
    disp(S);
end
```

Comment: You will need to normalize anisotropically so that you scale up the 0.6 or it will diminish exponentially compared to the 1 eigenvalue.

Comment: What do you mean when you write that “$S$ defines a subspace of dimension $k=2$”? What is normalization in this context?

Comment: I edited my post to include the code I used. Is my normalization incorrect?

Comment: No, normalization for dimensions greater than 1 should involve something like the QR decomposition, `S,R=qr(A*S)`. Then $S_kR_kR_{k-1}…R_1=A^kS_0$, so $S_k$ is an orthonormal basis of the space spanned by the rows of $A^kS_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization for dimensions greater than $1$ requires to find a basis with some fixed properties like orthonormality for the subspace in each step. This can be achieved by the QR decomposition,

```
[S,R]=qr(A*S).
```

Then 
$$
S_kR_kR_{k−1}…R_1=A^kS_0,
$$ 
so $S_k$ is an orthonormal basis of the space spanned by the rows of $M_k=A^kS_0$.

Executed (here in scilab) it results in the expected relatively slow linear convergence towards a diagonal matrix with a factor of $0.6$ or $1$ digit per $4.5$ steps in the off-diagonal elements.

```
for J=1:20
    [S,R] = qr(A*S); S
end
```

.

```
 S  =
  - 0.4856429  - 0.8741573    0.  
  - 0.8741573    0.4856429    0.  
    0.           0.           1.  
 S  =
  - 0.6794080  - 0.7337607    0.  
  - 0.7337607    0.6794080    0.  
    0.           0.           1.  
...

 S  =
  - 0.9999996  - 0.0008463    0.  
  - 0.0008463    0.9999996    0.  
    0.           0.           1.  
 S  =     
  - 0.9999999  - 0.0005078    0.  
  - 0.0005078    0.9999999    0.  
    0.           0.           1.  
 S  =
  - 1.0000000  - 0.0003047    0.  
  - 0.0003047    1.0000000    0.  
    0.           0.           1.  
...
```